# Unzipping potentially corrupt zip file

Tags: zip, file-corruption, unzip

I have the following file: `onedrive.zip`

When I try to `unzip` it:

```
unzip onedrive.zip
Archive:  onedrive.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
note:  onedrive.zip may be a plain executable, not an archive
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of onedrive.zip or
        onedrive.zip.zip, and cannot find onedrive.zip.ZIP, period.
```

However:

```
file onedrive.zip
onedrive.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract, compression method=store
```

Any chances for me to recover it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, winrar has a repair archive option.

1. Open archive with WinRAR
2. Click on Tools
3. Select Repair Archive
4. You can select a folder to put the recovered file in.

> Recovery Record – WinRAR products are designed to recover damaged files.

From [Winrar](https://www.win-rar.com/products-winrar.html?&L=0)

They also have a Linux, Mac and Android version.  I am not associated with them.